# unable to add meta data in orderitem using Woo commerce update order REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api, woocommerce

How to add meta data to every suborder (new data in order_item_meta table) using woocommerce rest API version v2? I have tried a lot but unable to see any changes in response on postman. I also tried to change the version but still no change.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code you have tried and any error messages you received.
See
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the submitted request and the response that you get?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266013/woocommerce-rest-api-issue-unable-to-add-order-item-meta-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved this by using hook:

```
function action_woocommerce_api_edit_order( $order_get_id, $data, $instance ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
    //$data = $response->get_data();

        for($i=0;$i<count($data['line_items']);$i++){
                for($y=0;$y<count($data['line_items'][$i]['meta']);$y++){
                    //echo "key";echo($res['line_items'][$i]['meta'][$y]['key']);echo "<br>";
                    //echo ($res['line_items'][$i]['meta'][$y]['value']);echo "value";
                    wc_update_order_item_meta($data['line_items'][$i]['id'],$data['line_items'][$i]['meta'][$y]['key'],$data['line_items'][$i]['meta'][$y]['value']);

                };

            }
}; 


// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_api_edit_order', 'action_woocommerce_api_edit_order', 10, 3 ); 
this will add data inside order_item_meta table w.r.t to every order_item.
```